# Force conda to create environment with win-32 platform

Tags: python, conda

I have a 32-bit version of Anaconda 2 with Python 2.7.10 installed on my Windows 10 machine, as well as a 64-bit version of Anaconda 3 with Python 3.5.0.  I need to create a new environment in the 32-bit version of Anaconda 2 so that I can do some development on a numerical simulation package.  However, when I open up the Anaconda2 prompt and try to create an environment using

```
conda create --name FMITest --clone root
```

the new environment is created using a win-64 platform, with Python 3.5.0 and the Anaconda3 root environment (though the default environment is Anaconda2\envs\FMITest).

How can I create a 32-bit Anaconda2 environment with Python 2.7.0 without uninstalling Anaconda3?

Comment: Since you have 2 conda installations, the environment will be created on the conda executable that you called with your 'conda' command. Make sure you're calling the correct 'conda'.

Comment: Bear in mind that having two installations of conda is not really supported. It will become very difficult to track which conda you're using (as you noticed). Also, cloning the root environment is not the best thing you can do because you don't want to end up with conda in non-root environments. Why don't you start from scratch, installing miniconda and then create multiple environments with anaconda2, 3, anything you fancy?